# hot to fix 'Can’t make {button returned:"Connect", text returned:"test"} into type Unicode text.'

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator

I'm trying to create a little automator app to connect to a wireless network via terminal on an **ssh'd** device where the network may be hidden.

A series of options leads to an option to simply type in an **SSID** and have the device connect.

```
set userSSID to display dialog "Type the SSID for the network you require below" buttons ["Connect", "Cancel"] default answer "" default button 1

            if button returned of result = "Cancel" then
                error number -128

            else

                if button returned of result = "Connect" then

                    tell application "Terminal"
                        set currentTab to do script ("networksetup -setairportpower en1 on")
                        delay 2
                        do script ("networksetup -setairportnetwork en1 '" & userSSID & "'") in currentTab
                    end tell
                end if
```

I'm expecting it to connect to the SSID as typed in, in this case "test", however I'm getting the error:

> The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “Can’t make {button
>   returned:"Connect", text returned:"test"} into type Unicode text.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display dialog` returns a record `{button returned, text returned}` as the error states.

To use the value of `text returned` you have to write

```
do script ("networksetup -setairportnetwork en1 '" & text returned of userSSID & "'") in currentTab
```

However there is some redundancy in your code, for example pressing the `Cancel` button aborts the script immediately.

The code can be reduced to

```
set {text returned:userSSID} to display dialog "Type the SSID for the network you require below" buttons ["Connect", "Cancel"] default answer "" default button 1
tell application "Terminal"
    set currentTab to do script ("networksetup -setairportpower en1 on")
    delay 2
    do script ("networksetup -setairportnetwork en1 '" & userSSID & "'") in currentTab
end tell
```

or maybe even without `Terminal.app`

```
set {text returned:userSSID} to display dialog "Type the SSID for the network you require below" buttons ["Connect", "Cancel"] default answer "" default button 1
do shell script "networksetup -setairportpower en1 on"
delay 2
do shell script "networksetup -setairportnetwork en1 " & quoted form of userSSID
```

Comment: Or even without  the `delay 2` statement and the second `do shell script` command  by chaining the two commands using the shells `&&` operator. For instance: `do shell script "networksetup -setairportpower en1 on && networksetup -setairportnetwork en1" & space & quoted form of userSSID`

Comment: I used both a combination of the non terminal approach suggested by vadian above and the chained command from RobC, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
set userSSID to display dialog "Type the SSID for the network you require below" buttons ["Connect", "Cancel"] default answer "" default button 1

if button returned of result = "Cancel" then
    error number -128
    
else
    
    if button returned of result = "Connect" then
        
        beep
    end if
    
end if
```